# Fix SESSION_REGISTER , SESSION_UNREGISTER Deprecated for PHP 5.3

Tags: php, php-5.3

I change my Code For Update To PHP 5.3 . For Fix This, i Remove `SESSION_REGISTER()` From My Code And Change `SESSION_UNREGISTER()` To `unset()`; this worked for me. this is true way ? This is a sure way ? PHP Manual ( [SESSION_REGISTER](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php) and [SESSION_UNREGISTER](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unregister.php) )

Old Code (SESSION_REGISTER) :

```
SESSION_REGISTER("UID");$_SESSION[UID]=$res->fields[uid];
SESSION_REGISTER("EMAIL");$_SESSION[EMAIL]=$res->fields[email];
SESSION_REGISTER("USERNAME");$_SESSION[USERNAME]=$res->fields[username];
SESSION_REGISTER("IS_ACTIVE");$_SESSION[IS_ACTIVE]=$res->fields[is_active];
```

TO

```
$_SESSION[UID]=$res->fields[uid];
$_SESSION[EMAIL]=$res->fields[email];
$_SESSION[USERNAME]=$res->fields[username];
$_SESSION[IS_ACTIVE]=$res->fields[is_active];
```

Old Code (SESSION_UNREGISTER) :

```
$_SESSION["UID"]    = ''; session_unregister("UID");
$_SESSION["EMAIL"]  = ''; session_unregister("EMAIL");
$_SESSION["USERNAME"]   = ''; session_unregister("USERNAME");
```

TO

```
unset($_SESSION["UID"]);
unset($_SESSION["EMAIL"]);
unset($_SESSION["USERNAME"]);
session_destroy();
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is a good way indeed.

Comment: Yes, that is correct way to go. You're doing it right

Comment: Quote your array indices! `$_SESSION[UID]` does not do what you think it does, it needs to be `$_SESSION['UID']`.

Comment: Also, if you're going to `session_destroy` anyway, no need to `unset` everything one by one before.

Comment: @deceze sure! thanks for better way.

Answer (score 0):

That's will work fine, just make sure you have your array keys quoted:

```
$_SESSION['UID']=$res->fields['uid'];
$_SESSION['EMAIL']=$res->fields['email'];
$_SESSION['USERNAME']=$res->fields['username'];
$_SESSION['IS_ACTIVE']=$res->fields['is_active'];
```